# 2 Dorpdown menus open same time

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

Hi i am using a `dropdown menu` in a `div`, it is working, but if I put 2 on the same page and I click in the first it opens  the first and the second at the same time. How can I handle this??

I have change `data-toggle="dropdown"` `id="dropdownMenuButton"` `aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"` but nothing seems to work. I am new to using bootstrap

My first dropdown

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <div href="#" class="form-control b-r" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-users"></i></div>
       <div class="dropdown-menu fadeInUp" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
       <label>Nº max</label>
             <div class="row pb-4" >
                 <div id="controls" class="text-center">
                       <div id="minus" class="btn btn-sm-click btn-info fa fa-minus pull-left"></div>
                           <input id="n_max" name="N_max" class="click select-form" readonly type="text" value="" >
                       <div id="plus" class="btn btn-sm-click btn-info fa fa-plus pull-right"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

My second dropdown

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <div href="#" class="form-control b-r" id="dropdownMenuButton_2" data-toggle="dropdown_2" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-users"></i></div>
       <div class="dropdown-menu fadeInUp" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton_2">
       <label>Nº max</label>
             <div class="row pb-4" >
                 <div id="controls" class="text-center">
                       <div id="minus" class="btn btn-sm-click btn-info fa fa-minus pull-left"></div>
                           <input id="n_max" name="N_max" class="click select-form" readonly type="text" value="" >
                       <div id="plus" class="btn btn-sm-click btn-info fa fa-plus pull-right"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

The goal is when click on first open the first and vice verse

Thanks for the help

Comment: u r html code is incomplete please add full code

Comment: ok miss the second dropdown

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: What id?? i have unique ids

Comment: I think you called js/jQuery code for toggle the dropdown menus.

Comment: The problem probably is jquery but i am using bootstrap how i can handle this ??

Answer (score 0):

I found your problem,

on second dropdown you add

`data-toggle="dropdown_2"`

it will be

```
data-toggle="dropdown"
```